# How can i get Class from Generic Type

Tags: java, reflection

I do not know how I will explain, I have a class something like

```
public class MyClass<T>{
    private Class <?> type;
    public MyClass(string className){
        this.type = Class.forName(className);
        Field[] fields = type.getDeclaredFields();//why i need type
    }
}
```

Then i create an object of that class:

```
MyClass<Person> persons = new MyClass<>("packageName.Person");
```

**Is there anyway to do this like**

```
MyClass<Person> persons = new MyClass<>();
```

Comment: You are calling the constructor `MyClass(string className)`, so it expects a String.

Comment: how can get that class name from T

Comment: like `typeof(T)` in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't because of the way generics are implemented in Java. You can often see a `Class<T> clazz` parameter being passed to work around it.

In fact, it doesn't make sense for you to pass in a `String`. Pass in `Person.class` instead, so you won't need the `Class.forName()`.